# How to get rid of `WARNING Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request'

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

**Situation:**

When requesting Google Bigquery from a python handler, this warnings shows up half a dozen of times

```
WARNING  2017-04-28 10:01:55,450 urlfetch_stub.py:550] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['content-length']
```

Then it either raise a deadline exception or successfully terminate the request.

```
HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response
```

(success / Deadline exception ration is approx 2 / 1)

Here is how I do the request from the python handler:

```
import uuid

from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
q = client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()),("SELECT * FROM my_table"))
q.use_legacy_sql = False
q.allowLargeResults = True
q.begin()
wait_for_job(q)
res = q.results()
```

**Question:** How to prevent the warning to occur ?

**Problem:** The warning returned by the query is caught as a failure by GAE and makes the handler to resend a query, so on until success or Deadline Exception [confirmation source](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/91). It is problematic as it multiply the time needed to execute a request.

**Extra information:**
In my current python handler I run three different requests one after the other. The number of `Warning` messages is the same for the three requests although it changes depending on time.
e.g.: 
request 1: 3 warnings, then request 2 and 3 will have Three time the warning message.
wait 5 min
request 1: 6 warnings, then request 2 and 3 will have Six time the warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning appear whith the new big query client.
This code works :

```
from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2

credentials = AppAssertionCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin')
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
query = "SELECT * FROM [" + table + "]"
           body = {'query': query, 'timeoutMs': 2000}
           result = service.jobs().query(projectId=PROJECT_ID, body=body).execute()
```

Comment: for me it still prints: 
WARNING  2017-05-11 14:42:36,149 urlfetch_stub.py:550] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['content-length']

Comment: Yes it does, but GAE doesn't catch it as an error no more, so it doesn't resend the query multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that GAE strips/modifies specific headers of all outbound HTTP requests by default: [see link here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-requests#request_headers). Additionally, after digging into the core HTTP helpers within the google-cloud-python client library, it looks like the default behavior is to add the `content-length` headers: [see code here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/e675367f36d3708e018f7eb6739cf9de02201051/core/google/cloud/_http.py#L186).

While none of this is ideal in your case, I don't think it should be a dealbreaker. I think that adding in a `try...catch` clause should help alleviate the pain, although you will continue to have these errors show up in the logs. Additionally, you could insert a `print type(e)` on exception e to find out more about the exception from your logs. See conversation [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/91)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But it didn't help as I already have been through those links...
`try...catch` is useless in my situation as I don't get any crash/error